# CSS auto change ul width; fit to MINIMUM width of children inline-block li's?

Tags: html, pagination, html-lists, css

I have a page with page buttons that are generated as an unordered list. They are styled so that the page buttons appear as a horizontal row. Because my ul is styled this way, I am having a hard time figuring out how to center it. The is getting its width set to 100% of the div that it's in. The buttons (each in a li) are aligned to the left side of the ul. I need the buttons to be centered in the middle of the div. However, because the ul is 100% width, I can't center the ul (in a sense, it already is centered). I'm not sure how to get the li's to center inside the ul; setting position on the li's to absolute doesn't work because then all of them get put in the same place, overlapping each other.

It would be fine if I could set the width of the ul to exactly that of its contents and then center the ul on the page, but I can't set the ul to a constant width because the width changes depending on how many pages there are; some searches result in 40 page, while other have only 1 page. What I really need is to get the ul to automatically fit to the width of the page buttons, but I don't know how to do that.

[Here's a fiddle I made to reproduce the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/ravencrowe/0ognotfd/)

the code:

```
<div class="SearchResults">

<div class="Event">
    <div class="">
         <h3>
         <a href="/faculty-and-research/faculty-directory/detail/?id=41432">
         This is an example of a search result that is loaded on the page. This is the full width of the content box; the page buttons should be centered under this box
         </a>
         </h3>
         <span> </span>
    </div>

</div>  

<div class="searchpagination">
    <ul>

        <li><a href="/WebAssets/Templates/EventSearchResults.aspx?page=8&q=&filters=&after=10%2f06%2f2014&before=10%2f31%2f2014" class="pageNavigator"><i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i></a></li>

        <li><a href="/WebAssets/Templates/EventSearchResults.aspx?page=1&q=&filters=&after=10%2f06%2f2014&before=10%2f31%2f2014" class="">1</a></li>

        <li><a href="/WebAssets/Templates/EventSearchResults.aspx?page=2&q=&filters=&after=10%2f06%2f2014&before=10%2f31%2f2014" class="">2</a></li>

        <li><a href="/WebAssets/Templates/EventSearchResults.aspx?page=3&q=&filters=&after=10%2f06%2f2014&before=10%2f31%2f2014" class="active">3</a></li>

        <li><a href="/WebAssets/Templates/EventSearchResults.aspx?page=...&q=&filters=&after=10%2f06%2f2014&before=10%2f31%2f2014" class="dots">...</a></li>

        <li><a href="/WebAssets/Templates/EventSearchResults.aspx?page=40&q=&filters=&after=10%2f06%2f2014&before=10%2f31%2f2014" class="">40</a></li>

        <li><a href="/WebAssets/Templates/EventSearchResults.aspx?page=10&q=&filters=&after=10%2f06%2f2014&before=10%2f31%2f2014" class="pageNavigator"><i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I added a red border to the div and a blue border to the ul. You can see that the ul is taking the whole width of the div, so centering the ul itself doesn't do anything because it's already centered... what needs to be centered is the boxes inside the ul

[image: ul]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to ul display:inline-block, and set for .searchpagination text-align:center;

Answer (score 3):

Set the `ul` to be an inline element and then use `text-align: center;` on the container. This will work for varying widths. Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ognotfd/1/)

```
.searchpagination {
    text-align: center;
}

.searchpagination ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0; /* remove initial padding to perfectly center */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some css like this to your "searchpagination"

```
margin: 20px auto;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
```

Margin 20px auto will center it. But this only works, if you enter a width for that element.

Just try it.